# Launch an activity without keeping it in the backstack

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to open **activity flow** as follow, what would be the correct/best approach to open flow of activity from Anywhere in Android app?

**Receive Push notification when user is on Activity A(app is in foreground) --->  Activity 1 opens, which will lead to activity 2 and activity 3. After finishing/closing activity 3 user should go back to activity A.**

Activity A can be any activity from Application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag for activity 1 and 2:

```java
// From activity A
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);

// From activity 1
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: In that case I need to add above code in every Activity (for example in activity A B C... so that whenever I receive push notification I can open activity 1,2,3..)

Comment: No, you should listen for push notification in a service and from the service launch the desired activity